# Oracle Golden Gate COLSEXCEPT at replication level

Tags: oracle, database-replication, oracle-golden-gate

I am using golden gate to replicate table from one DB to multiple DB's. The challenging part is that in one DB the table should be replicated full (all table columns), but in the rest of the DBs the table needs to be half replicated, meaning  just a few columns, not all.

Is it possible to have columns exception at the replication level ?

I know that is it possible at the extract level, but this doesn't fit to my scenario.

Comment: It is possible to map selected columns. What's the issue here ?

Comment: I suppose that you are referring at _COLMAP_ , but I'm not sure how it works. If I don't specify 'USEDEFAULTS' and you map only a few columns the rest of the cols which are not specified are ignored ?

Comment: Thanks for help, it works as expected with COLMAP.

Answer (score 0):

`COLSEXCEPT` is an `EXTRACT` parameter only. It cannot be used in replication.

For tables with large number of columns, using `COLEXCEPT` can help in excluding some columns instead of entering all the columns in the extract file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve this in the REPLICAT side by mapping the necessary columns to the target table using COLMAP. I think USEDEFAULTS will not work in this case for REPLICAT since you mentioned that you need few columns only(Does that mean the table structure is different from SOURCE to TARGET???)